# database inspection while debugging

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nhibernate, ssms, linqpad

I am trying out some cascade options with nhibernate mapping and have a unit test where I'd like to use a tool to inspect the state of the database. I was hoping I could use linqpad to do this, but the connection seems hung while in the debugger. I'd seen a demo not to long ago where SSMS was being used to inspect the db during a debug, so I'm wondering if I should be able to somehow use linqpad or if I need a different tool (I haven't installed SSMS on my laptop and would prefer something more light weight).

Unrelated to linqpad, my motivation for doing this is I am not sure if the db state I'm validating in a unit test is from the db or from nhibernate's cache? If Session.Flush() is called before the the assert, does that mean a fetch in an assert is guaranteed to be coming from the db?

Cheers,
Berryl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the second part of your question - Yes, calling session.flush() before any kind of fetch will push everything out to the DB. You could also do:

```
Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
//some hibernate interaction test code
t.commit()
//you can rest assured that any code coming from the hibernate now will
//be exactly what is in the db.
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Profiler (Tools > SQL Server Profile from SSMS) or [NHProf](http://nhprof.com/) will help you monitor commands sent to the database.

Comment: Hi Jamie

I can see sql statements sent to the db now just by configuring NHib to send them to the console. Its useful but I am looking for a lightweight tool that can inspect the db data during the debug.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DatabaseManagerSwing class included in [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/), it opens a Swing application that allows you to browse the objects in a db and also to run queries. Passing to it an open connection allows you to see the state of the database in the transaction the connection is in.

```
DatabaseManagerSwing manager = new DatabaseManagerSwing();
manager.main();
manager.connect(connection);
manager.start();
```